# Оптимизировать выделение элементов на диаграмме

Tags: angularjs, оптимизация, angular2

Мой код на Angular 2 работает в 10-15 раз медленнее, чем аналогичный на AngularJS.
Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

---

Есть массив следующегно вида (тут 1000 элементов)
http://pastebin.com/wZ82vVEb

```
data = [{col:25, y:96, color:"#ddfd51"}, {col:19, y:20, color:"#a05304"}, ...];
```

Для каждого значения `col` отображается `svg`-элемент (есть причины не рисовать всё на одном svg), содержащий прямоугольники с координатой `y` цвета `color`. Каждый из элементов можно выделять. Для этого есть набор чекбоксов, которые биндятся на поля `isSelected`.

В примерах столбцы превращены в строки для удобства отображения. Соответственно, для каждого `col` отображается `svg`-элемент-строка 1*100 с прямоугольниками с`x`-координатой равной `y`. Все прямоугольники распределены по двум группам `g`. Первая из них для невыделенных item'ов, вторая - для выделенных. Разделение на две группы требуется из-за того, что svg не поддерживает `z-index`, а координаты элементов могут совпадать, следовательно надо обеспечить, чтобы выделенные элементы шли в разметке после невыделенных.

### Вот так это выглядит на AngularJS

https://jsfiddle.net/1taex13L/5/

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
  var data = $scope.data = window.data; // See pastebin script
})

.controller('ChartController', function ($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.columns = [];
  for (var q=0; q<32; ++q) {
    $scope.columns.push($scope.data.filter(function (item) {
      return item.col === q;
    }));
  }

  $scope.falseTrue = [false, true];
})

.controller('SelectionController', function ($scope) {
})

.directive('bindAttrs', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.bindAttrs, function (val) {
      element.attr(val);
    })
  }
})

.filter('truthy', function () {
  return function (items, prop, val) {
    return items.filter(function (item) {
      return !!item[prop] === val;
    })
  }
})
```

```css
html { margin: 1em; }
figure { margin: 0 0 1em 0; border: 1px dotted; }
svg { display: block; width: 100%; }
g { opacity: .1; }
g.selected { opacity: 1; }
input { margin: 0; vertical-align: middle; }
label { display: inline-block; line-height: 1em; width: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw/wZ82vVEb"></script>

<main ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
  <figure ng-controller="ChartController">
    <svg ng-repeat="c in columns" viewBox="0 0 100 1">
      <g ng-repeat="sel in falseTrue" ng-class="{selected:sel}">
        <rect ng-repeat="r in c | truthy : 'isSelected' : sel"
              bind-attrs="{x:r.y, fill:r.color}" y="0" height="100%" width="1" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </figure>
  <div ng-controller="SelectionController">
    <label ng-repeat="item in data"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected"></label>
  </div>
</main>
```

### А так - на Angular 2

<s>http://plnkr.co/edit/IxbVrvpECWwpcCCDmIjK?p=preview</s>

Удалил то, что всё равно не работало, получилось так:
http://plnkr.co/edit/grj61gIizyCRmY8QpqEF?p=preview
плюс вопрос, [а на что же я подписался](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542043/178988)?

```
import {Component, View, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'chart-component',
  template: `
    <figure>
      <svg *ngFor="let c of columns" viewBox="0 0 100 1">
        <g *ngFor="let s of unselSel" [ngClass]="{selected:s==='sel'}">
          <rect *ngFor="let r of c[s]" [attr.x]="r.y" [attr.fill]="r.color" y="0" height="100%" width="1" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </figure>
  `
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() data : any[];

  columns : any[];
  unselSel = ['unsel', 'sel'];

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.columns = [];

    for (let q=0; q<32; ++q) {
      this.columns.push({sel:[], unsel:[]})
    }

    for (let item of this.data) {
      this.columns[item.col][item.isSelected ? 'sel' : 'unsel'].push(item);
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'selection-component',
  template: `
    <label *ngFor="let item of data"><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected"></label>
  `
})
export class SelectionComponent {
  @Input() data;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <chart-component [data]="data"></chart-component>
    <selection-component [data]="data" (change)="update()"></selection-component>
  `,
  directives: [ChartComponent, SelectionComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  data = window.data; // See pastebin

  update() {
    this.data = [].concat(this.data); // Clone array
  }
}
```

---

Замеры производительности в хроме показывают, что клик по чекбоксу в первом ангуляре обрабатывается менее 10 мс и в большинстве случаев не приводит к long-frame'ам (а если и приводит, то не длиннее 33 мс). А вот изменение чекбокса во втором варианте стабильно вызывает long frame длительностью около 150 мс. Как оптимизировать код?

Comment: не пойму что у тебя делает метод `onChanges` он же на каждый клик вызывается, но бежит в цикле, даже в двух

Comment: @Grundy, по идее, то же самое, что делали фильтры в первом. Распрелделяет все данные на колонки-строки и выбранность.

Comment: вот только в первом ты колонки один раз заполняешь, а тут каждый раз

Comment: @Grundy, предположим, в первом недоработка и это должно делаться фильтром. Но мне кажется, во втором что косяк второго начинается несколько раньше, а именно на `this.data = [].concat(this.data); // Clone array`. В любом случае, можешь исправить?

Comment: я вообще второй еще не особо смотрел :-) ну и сейчас времени нет. А кстати, зачем конкат тут?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что если ссылка на массив не изменится, он вообще `ngOnChanges` не вызывает...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42094/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Comment: Такой вариант вам подойдет? http://plnkr.co/edit/RwgxJKB3Hq8fKtwBPJVR?p=preview  Если да, давайте в ответе объясню детали

Comment: UPD. Хотя немного не прав, вам же надо чтоб все выделенные квадратики шли после невыделенных. Думаю это можно фильтром сделать и двумя *ngFor

Comment: @Alexandr, я уже до подобного добрался вроде: http://plnkr.co/edit/HSc6Iq4RVpK7YZoKlhcq?p=preview - всё равно медленнее, чем на первом, но на этот раз не сильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy отличие моего варианта в том что код инициализации в компоненте Chart вызывается только один раз. Была проблема в том что не выполнялось условие "Первая из них для невыделенных item'ов, вторая - для выделенных" но в приципе я придумал как с минимальными усилиями реализовать и такой вариант. Вы не пробовали проверить на производительность мой вариант?

Comment: @Alexandr, у меня тоже только один. `ngOnChanges` вызывается только на изменение ссылки на массив, но его я убрал. А раз ссылка никогда не меняется, то вызов будет всего один, так же, как `ngOnInit`. Пока не проверял, чуть позже гляну, но ожидаю, что будет примерно одинаково.