# Что за событие change во втором ангуляре?

Tags: angular2

Что за событие `change`, при каких условиях оно возникает и как его можно использовать?
Т. е. на что я подписался в следующем примере через `(change)="update()"`?

http://plnkr.co/edit/mfoToOSLU6IU2zr0A8OB?p=preview

```
import {Component, View, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'inner-component',
  template: `
    <label><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="data.isSelected"> Selected</label>
  `
})
export class InnerComponent {
  data = { isSelected: false };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p><inner-component (change)="update()"></inner-component></p>
    <p>The component was updated {{count}} times</p>
  `,
  directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0;

  update() {
    ++this.count;
  }
}
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/38227838/4928642)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541990/178988

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38227838/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это всплытие событий: `change` происходит на инпуте, но всплывает наверх, где его обрабатывает внешний компонент. Это можно проверить, если вывести событие:

http://plnkr.co/edit/J8pRg3ow41PAqdMteKwg?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <p><inner-component (change)="update($event)"></inner-component></p>
    <p>The component was updated {{count}} times</p>
  `,
  directives: [InnerComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  count = 0;

  update($event) {
    console.log($event, $event.target, $event.currentTarget);
    ++this.count;
  }
}
```