# Как в Angular элементы массива рассортировать по DOM в зависимости от условия

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular

Как рассортировать элементы массива по дом дереву в зависимости от значения ключа.

То есть есть массив с объектами задач и у задачи есть время то она попадает в один UL а если время равно NULL то в другой .
А так же не могу понять как передать например ID в атрибут тега

```
const tasks = [
  {name: 'задача1', time: NULL} //Задача должна попасть в UL 1
  name: 'задача2', time: 12:30} //Задача должна попасть в UL 2
]

<ul *ngIf="tasks" class="task1">//список задач со временем
  <li *ngFor="let task of tasks">{{task.name}} : {{task.time}}</li>
</ul>

<ul  *ngIf="tasks" class="task2">//список задач без времени
  <li>{{task.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: зачем вы проверяете `task`, который находится в массиве, а потом внутри итерируете `tasks`?

Comment: сори , тут ошибка, я проверяю  tasks, сейчас поправлю

Comment: track by зря не указываешь - тормозить будет при изменениях

Comment: @Qwertiy, не будет

Comment: @overthesanity, да ну? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541990/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, вы не сравнивайте обычную итерацию массива с тройной вложенностью директив и проделыванием "чего-то" на каждый ончейндж хук, там и трек бай может не помочь

Comment: @overthesanity, нет, там именно track by и помогает. С ним он переупорядочивает элементы, а без него всё сносит и полностью пересоздаёт. Я просто никак не соберусь ответ написать :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, я знаю что делает трек бай, я имел в виду, что от него нету толку на маленьких данных или одномерных массивах, к тому же механизм под капотом трек бай (`DefaultIterableDiffer`) также проделывает большую работу

Comment: @overthesanity, хм.. возможно, надо проверять...

Answer (score 0):

Четыре часа мучений через метод проб и ошибок и ответ найден

Рассортировал задачи в компоненте по двум переменным .
Пока учусь, возможно это не лучший вариант.

```
ngOnInit{
 this.hard_task = tasks.filter(task => task.time !== null);
 this.flexi_task = tasks.filter(task => task.time == null);
}
```

но остался вопрос почему все-таки если я передаю в атрибут например id="task.task_id" то он выводит в доме не айдишник а строку как есть id="task.task_id"

Comment: `[attr.id]="task.id"`

Comment: благодарю. сработало. вопрос окончательно решен